# How to identify the last item from pipeline foreach-object cmdlet

Tags: powershell

How do I determine if process is on the last item from a pipelined ForEach-Object cmdlet?

Example:
Let's say that I've previously defined connection for OLEDB to Access database to get the column definitions for each local table. I want list each of these columns with comma delimiter -- except when processing the LAST column. I want to omit the comma.

```
  ForEach($table in $Tables)
    { 
    $SchemaColumn = $Connection.GetSchema("Columns")
     $listarray = $schemaColumn |
     foreach-Object {

        If($_.Table_Name -eq $Table) { 

            IF "Last Item in Pipeline"   <---------------------------what would go here?
                {
                 "$($_.COLUMN_Name) $(Get-DataType($_.DATA_TYPE))"   <---- no comma!
                }
            ELSE   ## not the end of pipeline listing
                {
                 "$($_.COLUMN_Name) $(Get-DataType($_.DATA_TYPE)), "  <----yes comma!
                }
        }
     } #end Foreach-Object
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't already have the array generated you would want to do a full construct instead of piping to foreach.

```
$testarray = 1..10
Foreach ($Item in $TestArray) 
{
    if ($Item -eq $testarray[-1])
    { "last item in array is $Item"}
}
```

To clarify, each time through the array, it checks to see if $item matches the last item in $testarray. [-1] selects last item in array

But, in your case, since you already have the array stored in $SchemaColumn you could do the same thing as I said above with the pipeline..it would look like:

```
if ($_ -eq $SchemaColumn[-1]) { 'stuff' }
```

Comment: I really like your solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Might I suggest a different approach that doesn't rely on knowing whether it's the last item or not?

```powershell
ForEach($table in $Tables)
{ 
$SchemaColumn = $Connection.GetSchema("Columns")
 $listarray = $schemaColumn |
 foreach-Object {

    If($_.Table_Name -eq $Table) { 
             "$($_.COLUMN_Name) $(Get-DataType($_.DATA_TYPE))"  # <---- no comma!
    }
 } -join ',' #end Foreach-Object
```

Note the last line. The result of the `ForEach-Object` call (all of the "no comma" results) will be joined by `,` characters.

If this is not what you're looking for, can you explain how you would like to use the end result?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution. If you know the total number of items, you can use a counter to compare with:

```
$Total = $Items.count
$Counter = 0

foreach ($Item in $Items) {
    # This will run on the final iteration
    $Counter += 1
    if($Counter -ne $Total) {
        #This won't execute on the final iteration
    }
}
```

Comment: knowing the items count you can use FOR, not iterate using FOREACH

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could skip checking to see if it's the last column and then just trim trailing commas.

```
ForEach($table in $Tables)
{ 
$SchemaColumn = $Connection.GetSchema("Columns")
    $listarray = $schemaColumn | Where{$_.Table_Name -eq $Table} |
        foreach-Object {"$($_.COLUMN_Name) $(Get-DataType($_.DATA_TYPE)), "}
    $ListArray | ForEach{$_ = $_.TrimEnd(, )}
} #end Foreach-Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Return each column's information as a string. This will create an array, at which point you can use PowerShell's `-join` operator to join them with the comma.

```
foreach( $table in $Tables )
{
    $columns = $Connection.GetSchema('Columns') | 
                    Where-Object { $_.TABLE_NAME -eq $table } |
                    ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.COLUMN_Name,(Get-DataType $_.DATA_TYPE) }
    $columns -join ', '
}
```

It looks like you're writing a report of some kind. Instead of returning strings, have you considered returning objects?

```
$Connection.GetSchema('Columns') | 
    Select-Object -Property 'COLUMN_NAME',@{ Name = 'DATATYPE'; Expression = { Get-DataType $_.DATA_TYPE }},'TABLE_NAME'
```

Then someone could to this:

```
Get-Column |
    Sort-Object 'TABLE_NAME' |
    Format-Table -AutoSize -GroupBy 'TABLE_NAME' |
    Set-Content 'schema.txt'
```

Or this:

```
Get-Column |
    Export-Csv
```

Or this:

```
Get-Column |
    Sort-Object -Property 'TABLE_NAME' |
    Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ForEach-Object with script-blocks, you can do something for the last item in the -End script block like this:

```
$listarray = $schemaColumn |
  ForEach-Object 
  -Begin { $Previous = $null }
  -Process {
    If ( $Previous ) {
      ## Previous is not the last of pipeline listing
      "$($Previous.COLUMN_Name) $(Get-DataType($Previous.DATA_TYPE)), "  <----yes comma!
    }
    $Previous = $_ 
  }
  -End {
    ## Previous is the last item in pipeline
    "$($Previous.COLUMN_Name) $(Get-DataType($Previous.DATA_TYPE))"   <---- no comma!
  }
```